# Testing for empty arrays in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking for documents that have both 'e-campaigns' and 'p-campaigns' arrays that are non-empty:

```
 db.coll.find( { 'p-campaigns':{$ne:[]} ,  'e-campaigns' : {$ne:[]} }     )
```

I run the query on each array separately and do find docs with non-empty `p-campaigns` and `e-campaigns`, but the combined conditions turns out empty. I know there are documents with both `p-campaigns` and `e-campaigns` non-empty. I've tried using `$and`, with the same result: no docs with both arrays non-empty.

Am I going about this the right way? If not, why? This seems like the logical way to run this query on the conditions above. Thanks.

Comment: You can test for position 0, i.e.: `'e-campaigns.0':{$exists:true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my variant:

```
> db.a.save({x:[], y:[]})
> db.a.save({x:[1], y:[]})
> db.a.save({x:[], y:[1]})
> db.a.save({x:[1], y:[1]})
> db.a.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52248f5efb41276d1f3e3164"), "x" : [ ], "y" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52248f61fb41276d1f3e3165"), "x" : [ 1 ], "y" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52248f66fb41276d1f3e3166"), "x" : [ ], "y" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52248f69fb41276d1f3e3167"), "x" : [ 1 ], "y" : [ 1 ] }
> db.a.find({ 'x':{$ne:[]} ,  'y' : {$ne:[]} })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52248f69fb41276d1f3e3167"), "x" : [ 1 ], "y" : [ 1 ] }
```

Comment: It's comforting to see I do understand the querying, but clearly I'm clobbering records with my updates. Back to the manual... Thanks.

Comment: this won't work if the field doesn't exist at all - it only works if it's guaranteed to be exactly an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

For empty array in mongoDb filter query:

```
{field: {$size: 0}} // When find field array size is 0 or empty.
```